# Sql query (select * where) doesn't work in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
    <?php
$mysqli_host = 'localhost';
$mysqli_user = 'root';
$mysqli_pass = '';
$mysqli_db = 'fives';

$link = mysqli_connect($mysqli_host,$mysqli_user,$mysqli_pass,$mysqli_db);

if (isset($_GET['username'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_GET['username']);
    print $username. "<br>";
    if (!empty($username)) {
        $username_query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM users");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($username_query)) {
                print "username: " . $row["username"]. " - password: " . $row["Password"]. " - date:" . $row["date"]. "<br>";
            }
            print $username_result = mysqli_num_rows($username_query) . "<br>";//print 1

            $username_query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username . "'");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($username_query)) {
                print "username: " . $row["username"]. " - password: " . $row["Password"]. " - date:" . $row["date"]. "<br>";
            }
            print $username_result = mysqli_num_rows($username_query);//print 0
    }
}
?>
```

what it prints is

```
yariv
username: "yariv" - password: "1234" - date:2015-08-26
1
0
```

well there's no problem with the first query.. it gets all of the data from [Users] which is 1 row, but when im trying to get it by using `where username = '" . $username . "'` the sql query gets 0 rows.
why is it like that?

Comment: you sure that your form is using a GET method?

Comment: Have you echoed the query and confirmed `$username` is as expected?

Comment: Try to change your `$username` print to: `print strlen($username).' '.$username. "<br>"` to see if there are any "hidden" characters that might ruin the SQL statement.

Comment: `$username` may be failing. As I stated, if your form (if you're using one) is using a POST method rather than a GET, then that will be failing you. Next to impossible to answer without knowing how/where `$username` is coming from. Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: the srlen method return 5 as it is suppose to be.

Comment: $username is typed in by me.http://localhost/fives/checkuserexist.php?username=yariv    @Fred-ii-

Comment: Ok, I've just noticed you have double-quotes in your user and password printout which are not supposed to be there. Your database doesn't have the username `yariv` but it actually has the username `"yariv"`! Check it with sending "yariv" instead of yariv and see if it works.

Comment: what @uri2x said, and/or the spaces in `'" . $username . "'` could be an issue. Try changing that to `'".$username."'` it could be adding spaces here. Plus, if there are quotes in your table, then that was probably caused at the INSERT level.

Comment: do a `var_dump($_GET['username']);` and `var_dump($username_query);` for the 2nd query. Results are?

Comment: so, where are we at with the question and comments posted? @ me if you need me. I am moving on. Good luck

Comment: Thank you! @uri2x that was the problem- yariv instead of "yariv"

Answer (score 0):

The first query shows the result because you did not compare the given user name to the username existing in the database, but in the second query you were cheeking the username to the database username. so are you sure that you gave the correct user name same as the username in the database?